# Putting interfaces in one interface

Tags: solidity, interfaces

A noob question: is it possible or a good practice to put interfaces into one master interface such that all contracts in a DApp only import one interface?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for an interface to inherit from multiple interfaces in Solidity.
Is it good practice? It depends. See [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Sometimes these principles are negligible though in the dApp development because of gas optimization and other restrictions such as a limit on the amount of bytecode, but as Solidity is object(contract)-oriented you may find these principles useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Putting all into one is one possible solution I had in mind. I was also wondering if there is a better practice of interface management. Imagine importing and declaring 10+ interfaces (may not be a lot), this is a little component that takes disproportional amount of effort to manage.